# Swagger Editor Parameter Errors

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm trying to draft up an API in Swagger for easy viewing through SwaggerUI, but I'm encountering errors I don't quite understand. As far as I can tell, I'm adhering to the specification.

```
/history/tags/{tag_id}:
  get:
    summary: "Gets the history of this tag."
    description: "Warning: not using both the start and end date fields may result in excessively long responses."
    operationId: "get_tag_history"
    produces:
    - "application/json"
    parameters:
    - name: "tag_id"
      in: "path"
      description: "UUID for this tag."
      type: "string"
      required: true
    - name: "start_date"
      in: "query"
      description: "Start date for history"
      type: "String"
      foramt: "date"
      required: false
    - name: "end_date"
      in: "query"
      description: "End date for history"
      type: "String"
      foramt: "date"
      required: false
    responses:
      200:
        description: "Operation success"
        schema: 
          $ref: "#/definitions/Tag_history"
      400:
        description: "Invalid request"
```

The second and third parameters are throwing `Schema error at paths./history/tags/{tag_id}.get.parameters[1]
is not exactly one from <#/definitions/parameter>,<#/definitions/jsonReference>` (or `parameters[2]`, depending on which parameter).

Most other problems I've seen are simply people forgetting to use `schema:`, but that isn't how query parameters are structured. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
type: "String"
foramt: "date"
```

to

```
type: "string"
format: "date"
```

`type` is case-sensitive, and `format` was misspelled.

Comment: Well that's just embarrassing... Thank you.